# How to fetch different html file in a single WebView in android studio

Tags: android, html, android-activity, webview

I am a beginner and i am trying to make an app for a book which has 15 chapters, and each chapter has say 25 topics. On the main activity i want 15 buttons with ch. names, and when clicked on a button it takes to another activity which has 25 buttons with topics, and when clicked on a topic it fetch an html file from the assets folder and show it in a new activity which has a webview. Now my ques is how can i fetch respective html file when a button is clicked on the same activity? Or i have to use diff activity for each topic. That will be very lengthy (more than 300) activities.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You should save the Web view calling method in a Util Class and load URL with corresponding to your Activity

    Ex: wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                wv1.loadUrl(url);

    And Then pass URL as String to your activity 
eg. String url = ed1.getText().toString();
```